# Reoccurring string-formatting within a list upon access in python

Tags: python, list, string-formatting

In python, is it possible to have a reoccurring string-formatting operation take place when an item in a list is accessed?

For example:

```
>>>from random import randint
>>>a = ["The random number is: {0}".format(randint(0,10))]
>>>print a[0]
The random number is: 3
>>>print a[0]
The random number is: 3
```

Obviously it's obtaining a random integer, formatting the string and saving it in the list when the list is first defined. Performance hit aside, I'd like to know if it is possible to override this behavior.

I know if I were to see this question I would respond with something like "you're doing it wrong" and would provide something similar to the below answer...

```
>>>a = ["The random number is: {0}"]
>>>print a[0].format(randint(0,10))
```

But lets assume that's not a solution for this question. I'd really like for the formatting to be defined and take place in the list itself (if possible).

Another example:

```
a = ["The some sweet string: {0}".format(someFunction),
     "Another {0} different string {1}".format(someFunctionTwo, someFunctionThree)]
```

Where someFunction* provides a "random" result upon each call.

I know its a bit of a stretch and I may have to rely on the methods provided already ( thanks for your feedback ) but, I figured I'd give it a shot.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class and override `__str__`:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...        return "The random number is: {0}".format(randint(0,10))
... 
>>> a = [Foo()]
>>> print a[0]
The random number is: 8
>>> print a[0]
The random number is: 10
>>> print a[0]
The random number is: 5
```

But you're right, my first inclination is to say that you're *probably* doing it wrong...

---

Here's another idea -- keep your lists with format strings in them:

```
a = ["The some sweet string: {func1}",
     "Another {func2} different string {func3}"]

for item in a:
   print item.format(func1=func1(),func2=func2(),func3=func3())
```

Obviously this isn't efficient (as you call functions when you don't necessarily need them ...), but it could work.

Comment: NB I don't think a [class is warranted](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes) in cases like this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could subclass `list` and define `def __getitem__(self, i): return list.__getitem__(self, i).format(random.randint(0, 10))` or something, but that makes me feel silly even writing it..

Comment: @delnan -- I agree.  But I don't know what else OP is looking for ... In any other case (e.g. a function), you will need to explicitly call *something* which it seems like that is what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @DSM -- Interesting idea.  That would make me feel pretty silly too -- (not that I didn't already feel a little dirty after creating the code that I posted above)

Comment: Sure, it is a bit of a silly question. Perhaps a poor example. The idea is that, each item could have different formatting rules assigned. One item in the list may only have one argument in the string formatting, another item in the list two or three completely different ones. Instead of creating classes, or a function for each possibility I was hoping I could use a method similar to the one I listed above. Oh well. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @RyanAdams -- I'm still a little confused what you're going for here.  Could you use keywords?  `['the random number is {rand}','the foo is {bar}']` and then loop over the list creating your strings by:  `item.format(rand=randint(0,10),bar="baz is qux")`?

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use a function for this:

```
In [1]: from random import randint

In [2]: def func():
   ...:     return "The random number is: {0}".format(randint(0,10))
   ...: 

In [3]: func()
Out[3]: 'The random number is: 7'

In [4]: func()
Out[4]: 'The random number is: 2'

In [5]: func()
Out[5]: 'The random number is: 3'
```